# Check for native show password feature

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

In IE11 there's a toggle button in password fields, to show or hide the password:

[image]

Is there a way to check if this native feature is implemented in a browser, through JavaScript?

Comment: Aside from detecting IE11 (Browser detection: bad idea), I doubt it.

Comment: I don't think browser detection is that bad of an idea when the "feature" is non-standard.

Comment: Even with browser detection, that feature can be disabled through group policy or registry settings. Therefore, the button may not exist even if `("ActiveXObject" in window && !window.ActiveXObject)` yields `true`. You *may* be able to abuse styling the `::-ms-reveal` CSS pseudo-element to detect the button's presence, but that would be sketchy at best.